# Multiple checkbox in excel and selected value should go to adjacent columns and store it

Tags: excel

I have created multiple checkbox in a single row and I have 2000+ rows the requirement is if we select multiple options in a single row the values should use ";" as a divider and store it in adjacent column.

**Reference image**

[image: Reference image]

I have made this and now I want to store selected options to store in "Insert Column."